# Is there a way to exit a cell editing session without making any changes if an incorrect value is entered?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using two different macros in my excel sheet to do the following:
#1 Allow for multiple dates to be entered into the same cell (separated by a comma)
#2 Only allow dates to be entered in DD/MM/YYYY format from 01/01/2000 to the present day.

There are issues that occur when an incorrect value is entered in the cell, and I need a better way to handle the errors.

If, for example, there is already a date in the cell, and a second invalid value is added (for example, a date in the future, such as 01/01/2024), an error message will pop up, and will either let the user click Retry to enter a different value, or Cancel to exit cell editing. However, sometimes (not always) when I click Cancel, all the cell values are deleted (even the correct values that were in there before).

As I mentioned, sometimes this error occurs, and sometimes it doesn't. But it is a major problem because if an invalid value is accidently entered in a cell, all cell contents may be deleted, and excel does not allow me to undo this action.

So I am looking for a way to exit cell editing without changing any cell values if an invalid value is entered into a cell.

Here are the macros:
#1

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Written by Philip Treacy
' https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/select-multiple-items-from-drop-down-data-validation-list

    Dim OldVal As String
    Dim NewVal As String
    
    ' If more than 1 cell is being changed
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("Date_Entry")) Is Nothing Then
    
        ' Turn off events so our changes don't trigger this event again
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        NewVal = Target.Value
        
        ' If there's nothing to undo this will cause an error
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Undo
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        OldVal = Target.Value
        
        ' If selection is already in the cell we want to remove it
        If InStr(OldVal, NewVal) Then
        
            'If there's a comma in the cell, there's more than one word in the cell
            If InStr(OldVal, ",") Then
            
                If InStr(OldVal, ", " & NewVal) Then
                
                    Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, ", " & NewVal, "")
                
                Else
                
                    Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, NewVal & ", ", "")
                
                End If
                
            Else
            
                ' If we get to here the selection was the only thing in the cell
                Target.Value = ""
            
            End If
        
        Else
        
            If OldVal = "" Then
        
                Target.Value = NewVal
            
            Else
            
                ' Delete cell contents
                If NewVal = "" Then
            
                    Target.Value = ""
                
                Else
            
                    ' This IF prevents the same value appearing in the cell multiple times
                    ' If you are happy to have the same value multiple times remove this IF
                    If InStr(Target.Value, NewVal) = 0 Then
                    
                        Target.Value = OldVal & ", " & NewVal
                
                    End If
                
                End If
            
            End If
            
        End If
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True
            
    Else
    
        Exit Sub
        
    End If

End Sub
```

#2

```
Sub customised_validation_dates()

With ActiveSheet.Range("Date_Entry").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="01/01/2000", Formula2:="=TODAY()"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .ErrorTitle = "Invalid Date"
    .ErrorMessage = "Input must be date between 01/01/2000 and today. Date must also be entered in DD/MM/YYYY format."
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: "More than word in the cell": won't "01/01/2001, 02/02/2002" fail the validation?

Comment: @dcromley that line adds a comma to the end of whatever string value has already been entered. these codes work perfectly when correct values are entered into the cells.