# How to add a custom error handler to the add validation method?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to add data validation to my cells. However instead of using the AlertStyle argument provided in the Add method, I want to create a custom error handler. Reason being, the AlertStyles provided by VBA do not force the user to abort cell editing if an incorrect value is added. The user can select "Retry" or "Cancel", and sometimes, when they hit "Cancel", all cell contents are lost (if there was only one value previously in the cell. If there was more than one value previously in the cell, no values are lost). So I'd rather create an error handler that exits the Sub when the user enters invalid data.

Here's my attempt:

```
Sub customised_validation_dates_2()



With ActiveSheet.Range("Date_Entry").Validation

On Error GoTo err

    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, _
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="01/01/2000", Formula2:="=TODAY()"
    .IgnoreBlank = True

err: Exit Sub
    
End With


End Sub
```

but when an invalid date is entered, a message box still pops up, prompting the user to either retry data entry or cancel data entry, but like I said, if there is exactly one value previously in the cell and the user hits "Cancel", the cell value is lost.

extra context:

I have another macro running that allows the user to enter multiple values in one cell. So what I am trying to do is, if in the cell there is already another value, and the user tries adding another value that is invalid, I want to exit cell editing without giving the user the option to retry or cancel data entry, which is the root of my issue (because when they hit "cancel" and there is already a value in the cell, that other value gets erased).

Comment: Do you understand what your code tries doing? The code you show **only adds the validation** and skip any error, if any (during validation adding). It has nothing to do with validation itself behavior. What do you want the code doing in case of pressing "Cancel"? To let there a value not being on the validation list? When you say "all cell contents are lost", how do you like the validation to behave?

Comment: Should probably provide more context - assuming this is related to your previous question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74634988/is-there-a-way-to-exit-a-cell-editing-session-without-making-any-changes-if-an-i   With this complexity you might be better off using a userform to populate/edit these cells ?

Comment: @FaneDuru   my code checks to see if a date value is entered within the desired date range. if the user tries to enter an invalid value, the Add method prompts a message box that gives the user the chance to either retry entering the value or cancel the edit session. however I have another macro running that lets the user add multiple items to the same cell. so what happens is I need to modify the Add method such that if the user tries to enter an invalid value, the edit session will end without modifying what was previously in the cell.

Comment: @TimWilliams so I made this question separate because the Add method has a default error handler that seems to be the issue in this situation. plus also I think the other macro in my other question overcomplicated my question and I want the focus to be on this Add method because I believe that's where my problem is stemming from.

Comment: As @FaneDuru points out though - your code only *sets up* the validation.  By the time the user is entering ant data the posted code is done and dusted.

Comment: @TimWilliams could you explain that differently? I'm having a hard time following the point you are both making

Comment: @TimWilliams also a user form is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Your posted code does not run when a user enters data in the cell, so there's no way that error handler could get invoked on data entry.  Your error handler only applies to setting up the validation rule, so if you tried to apply an invalid setting, then it would get triggered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250060/discussion-between-brenda-thompson-and-tim-williams).

Comment: What you try explaining now is exactly what data validation does in its original way of working. If "the edit session will end without modifying what was previously in the cell" should men to **let the input value in the cell** is exactly what Data Validation tries to avoid!

Answer (score 1):

I think you've gotten confused about your errors. Your code relating to errors (`on error` and `err`)  is related to [VBA errors](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/) and has nothing to do with cell validation.

To illustrate a error walkthrough example...

```vb
Sub exampleOfErrorHandling()

    Dim aResponse As String
        aResponse = InputBox("Enter something. Text will trigger an error while a nubmer will be accepted.")
    If aResponse = "" Then Exit Sub

    'programs procedure to jump to section problem with an error
    On Error GoTo ProblemZone
    Dim anyNumber As Integer 'variable will only accept number
        anyNumber = aResponse
        
    On Error GoTo 0 'sets errors to be handled in default method
    
    MsgBox anyNumber & " is a valid number"
    
    'section where other code would typically be inserted
    
    Exit Sub 'where normal code would end
    
ProblemZone:
    'section to handle errors
    Dim tryAgain As Long
    
    tryAgain = MsgBox(aResponse & " is not a number. Try again?", vbYesNo + vbCritical)
    
    If tryAgain = vbYes Then Call exampleOfErrorHandling

End Sub
```

What it appears you want is something with cell validation. You might consider trying the record macro while setting validation to capture exactly what you want. Then engineer that to set the validation as you prefer.

Alternatively, you could use the change event to remove prior values if they don't meet requirement. Here's example of requiring cell A2 to be numeric. Note this must be in the sheet module, not the typical `Modules` section.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'cell A2 must be a number

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not IsNumeric(Me.Range("A2")) Then
        MsgBox "A2 is not numeric"
        Application.Undo
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: so just to connect things a little bit -- I thought the code I posted was cell validation? using the Add Validation method in excel? I'm just not sure I am following the distinction that you are making between the code you wrote vs the Add Validation method in excel

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what you're trying to do as your insertion of `On Error GoTo err` and then `err exit sub` doesn't make sense (to me). Again those lines have nothing to do with your cell validation. The area in between is indeed related to CELL validation, but why turn on vba error handler there? I just had this code lying around and posted it to maybe help out. If not, I can delete, not a big deal.

Comment: Your statement here is what to me suggests major confusion: *So I'd rather create an error handler that exits the Sub when the user enters invalid data.*  as this error handler has nothing to do with a user input.